# Sed Range of Patterns only if it contains Pattern

Tags: sed, range

What i would like to know is how to print a Range of Patterns but only if it contains a specific Pattern.

For example:

I have a file that contains:

```
       HEADER 1
  AAA
  BBBBBBB
  MSG:testing
  CCCCCC
  DDD
      PAGE 1

   HEADER 2
EEE
FFFFFF
GGG
HHH
   PAGE 2
```

I want to print from any `HEADER` to any `PAGE` but only if it contains the pattern `MSG`

The result i want is to print only these section:

```
      HEADER 1
  AAA
  BBBBBBB
  MSG:testing
  CCCCCC
  DDD
      PAGE 1
```

What i have so far is: `sed -n -e '/HEADER /,/PAGE /p' inputfile.txt > outputfile.txt`

I'm open to any suggestions including the usage of Awk or Grep.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

This

```
sed '/HEADER/ { :a N; /PAGE/!ba; /MSG/!d }' inputfile.txt
```

works as follows:

```
/HEADER/ {        # in a line that contains HEADER
  :a              # jump label for looping
  N               # fetch next line, append to pattern space
  /PAGE/!ba       # if the pattern space doesn't contain PAGE (this
                  # is the case if the new line doesn't), go back to :a

  /MSG/!d         # if the block that's now in the pattern space doesn't
                  # contain MSG, discard it
}
```

This removes offending ranges from the file and leaves everything else intact. To print only matching ranges and discard garbage data between ranges,

```
sed -n '/^HEADER/ { :a N; /PAGE/!ba; /MSG/p }' inputfile.txt
```

This removes the default print action with `-n` and uses `/MSG/p` to explicitly print matching ranges instead of deleting non-matching ranges.

Comment: Thks for the quick answer, sadly it is not so simple, i tried the above soluttion and it seems it entered on a infinite loop, because the example i showed is not entirely accurate, the real file is a big text file with a lot of garbage info and i want to filter but the specific lines didnt start with the text in question but only contains the text. So i replaced by real info that i want is something like: sed '/SUBCASE / { :a N; /PAGE/!ba; /F O R C E S/!d }}' inputfile.txt or even ed '/SUBCASE / { :a N; /\nPAGE/!ba; /\nF O R C E S/!d }}' inputfile.txt both of this didin´t work

Comment: Can you add example input and output that matches the real input to the question? I have some difficulty imagining what you mean, so I had to guess in the edit.

Answer (score 0):

If your date is separated bye space, you can use this `gnu awk`

```
awk -v RS= '/MSG/' file
HEADER 1
AAA
BBBBBBB
MSG:testing
CCCCCC
DDD
PAGE 1
```

By setting  `RS` to nothing, `awk` works in block mode, and then just select the correct block.

---

This use  `HEADER` as separator.

```
awk -v RS="HEADER" '/MSG/ {print RS$0}' file
HEADER 1
AAA
BBBBBBB
MSG:testing
CCCCCC
DDD
PAGE 1
```

Comment: Thks it worked!!, the long time i seached for these info, you saved my life.

Comment: @SpiderRider You are welcome.  Feel free free to accept it when you have sufficient credit.

Comment: One question sometimes i have one error:

This is my real data:

$ awk -v RS="SUBCASE 2402001" '/S T R E S S E S/ {print RS$0}' calc_run_00_fwdii_ultimate_tpos_ff.f06 > ff1.txt
awk: cmd. line:1: (FILENAME=calc_run_00_fwdii_ultimate_tpos_ff.f06 FNR=352829) fatal error: internal error
Aborted (core dumped)

Comment: @SpiderRider Can you update original post.  Hard to read data in comment. Also post what system you are on and `awk --version`

Answer (score 0):

```
sed -n '/^HEADER/,/^PAGE /!d;H;/^HEADER/h;/^PAGE / {x; /\nMSG/ p;}' YourFile
```

Assuming there is only and always section starting with HEADER and ending with PAGE (on different lines)

Explaination:

- Dont print output unless print is asked
- If line is not between (including) `HEADER` and `PAGE`, remove it
- Append line to holding buffer
- if line is `HEADER` write it to holding buffer (overwrite)
- if line is `PAGE`

  - load the holding buffer to working buffer
  - print if MSG is inside
- cycle

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '/HEADER/!{H;$!d};x;/MSG/!d' file
```

If the line does not contain `HEADER` append it to the hold space and if it is not the last line delete it. This means any other line (lines that contain `HEADER` or last line) will swap with the hold space and if the pattern space (a multiline previously the hold space) does not contain `MSG` delete it. Lines containing `MSG` will be printed.